# Deserializing Client-Side AJAX JSON Dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, ajax, date

Given the following JSON Date representation:

```
"\/Date(1221644506800-0700)\/"
```

How do you deserialize this into it's JavaScript Date-type form?

I've tried using MS AJAX JavaScrioptSerializer as shown below:

```
Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize("\/Date(1221644506800-0700)\/")
```

However, all I get back is the literal string date.

Comment: Are you using jQuery maybe? Check my blog post to auto convert dates so you don't have to do it manually. http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/converting-dates-in-json-strings-using.html

Comment: See my comments below. Your blog's code fails on dates before the epoch.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Provided you know the string is definitely a date I prefer to do this :

```
 new Date(parseInt(value.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10))
```

Comment: This worked for me, my ToJson method was serializing DateTimes as "\/Date(1251795081950)\/"

Comment: Thank you. `var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));` works too.

Answer (score 18):

Bertrand LeRoy, who worked on ASP.NET Atlas/AJAX, [described the design of the JavaScriptSerializer DateTime output](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/01/18/dates-and-json.aspx) and revealed the origin of the mysterious leading and trailing forward slashes.  He made this recommendation:

> run a simple search for "\/Date((\d+))\/" and replace with "new Date($1)" before the eval
>   (but after validation)

I implemented that as:

```
var serializedDateTime = "\/Date(1271389496563)\/";
document.writeln("Serialized: " + serializedDateTime + "<br />");

var toDateRe = new RegExp("^/Date\\((\\d+)\\)/$");
function toDate(s) {
    if (!s) {
        return null;
    }
    var constructor = s.replace(toDateRe, "new Date($1)");
    if (constructor == s) {
        throw 'Invalid serialized DateTime value: "' + s + '"';
    }
    return eval(constructor);
}

document.writeln("Deserialized: " + toDate(serializedDateTime) + "<br />");
```

This is very close to the many of the other answers:

- Use an anchored RegEx as Sjoerd Visscher did -- don't forget the ^ and $.
- Avoid string.replace, and the 'g' or 'i' options on your RegEx.  "/Date(1271389496563)//Date(1271389496563)/" shouldn't work at all.

Comment: A very good answer.... shame i found it at the bottom of the list for the question.

Comment: That regex won't work for dates before the epoch, which have a negative value. You need something like this: `/\/Date\((-?\d+)(?:-\d+)?\)\//i`

Answer (score 11):

A JSON value is a string, number, object, array, true, false or null. So this is just a string. There is no official way to represent dates in JSON. This syntax is from the asp.net ajax implementation. Others use the ISO 8601 format.

You can parse it like this:

```
var s = "\/Date(1221644506800-0700)\/";
var m = s.match(/^\/Date\((\d+)([-+]\d\d)(\d\d)\)\/$/);
var date = null;
if (m)
  date = new Date(1*m[1] + 3600000*m[2] + 60000*m[3]);
```

Comment: My toJson method was spitting out serialized dates as "\/Date(1251795070160)\/", which your code doesn't parse. I'll work out why later, just posting here for others

Comment: +1 for making it clear what a JSON value can be and that dates are not one of them, but a custom format.

Comment: That regex won't work for dates before the epoch, which have a negative value. You need this: `/\/Date\((-?\d+)(?:-\d+)?\)\//i`

Comment: @Sjoerd: Do you have to add the timezone or subtract it to convert it to UTC? I am confused because if I see a time as `1/1/2000 0:0:0 +0500` (i think) I have to subtract 5 hours to get UTC time.

Comment: You could fallback to parseInt if no timezone is specified `if (date == null) 
    date = new Date(parseInt(s.substring(6, s.length - 2), 10));`

Answer (score 6):

The regular expression used in the ASP.net AJAX deserialize method looks for a string that looks like "/Date(1234)/" (The string itself actually needs to contain the quotes and slashes). To get such a string, you will need to escape the quote and back slash characters, so the javascript code to create the string looks like "\"\/Date(1234)\/\"".

This will work.

```
Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize("\"\\/Date(1221644506800)\\/\"")
```

It's kind of weird, but I found I had to serialize a date, then serialize the string returned from that, then deserialize on the client side once.

Something like this.

```
Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jss = new Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string script = string.Format("alert(Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize({0}));", jss.Serialize(jss.Serialize(DateTime.Now)));
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ClientScript", script, true);
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that it doesn't look at the timezone:
Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize("\"\\/Date(1221644506800+0200)\\/\"")
Will results the same as:
Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize("\"\\/Date(1221644506800+0300)\\/\"")

Answer (score 3):

For those who don't want to use Microsoft Ajax, simply add a prototype function to the string class.

E.g.

```
    String.prototype.dateFromJSON = function () {
    return eval(this.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)"));
};
```

Don't want to use eval? Try something simple like

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```

As a side note, I used to think Microsoft was misleading by using this format. However, the JSON specification is not very clear when it comes to defining a way to describe dates in JSON.

Comment: That regex won't work for dates before the epoch, which have a negative value. You need this: `/\/Date\((-?\d+)(?:-\d+)?\)\//i`

Answer (score 2):

Actually, momentjs supports this kind of format, you might do something like:

```
    var momentValue = moment(value);

    momentValue.toDate();
```

This returns the value in a javascript date format

Answer (score 1):

The big number is the standard JS time

```
new Date(1221644506800)
```

Wed Sep 17 2008 19:41:46 GMT+1000 (EST)